# Is there an example of forking and communicating with a subprocess in D?

Tags: fork, pipe, d, popen

How do you fork and communicate with a subprocess in D?

I think I'm pretty much looking for http://erdani.com/d/new-stdio/phobos-prerelease/std_process.html#pipeProcess but pipeProcess doesn't seem to be in D2.

I want to execute a child process and be able to read from its stdout and stderr, write to its stdin and receive notification of it exiting and its exit code.

What is the best way of doing this in D?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: I believe that that documentation was posted for a discussion on proposed changes to std.stdio, and its page on std.process is probably for what will eventually be the new std.process (since the developer who was proposing changes to std.stdio is involved in the rewriting of std.process), but there's a bug in Digital Mars' C runtime which makes it so that the new std.process doesn't work on Windows yet (and it would probably affect this, since it has to do with pipes). It should end up in Phobos in one form or another eventually though.

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know.  My enthusiasm for D is largely based on how simply useful things can be written in cross-platform way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually this functionality will be in Phobos, but for now, here's a class I tossed together: [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/CBYw4fDU)

You use it like this:

```
auto stream = new ProcessStream("ls -a");
// read, write, etc. from stream
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, same way as you would in C. pipe, fork, exec.

Not pretty.